According to Trinitarians, how could Jesus (God the Son) be GIVEN life in Himself (John 5:26), if he shares the same essence of being than the Father?
A similar question has been asked here, but no details have been asked other than how Trinitarians interpret this verse. The top answer of the linked question talks about the Son being "eternally begotten" by the Father, and the Son proceeding from the Father (something I have not found in any of the Chalcedonian Creeds). My question is less about the Son's origin, but about the Father and the Son sharing the same divine essence.
Thus, here is a more detailed question for this bible passage. Let me quote it first in its immediate context:

24 Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that heareth my word, and
believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and shall not
come into condemnation; but is passed from death unto life.
25 Verily, verily, I say unto you, The hour is coming, and now is,
when the dead shall hear the voice of the Son of God: and they that
hear shall live.
26 For as the Father hath life in himself; so hath he given to the Son
to have life in himself;
John 5:24-26 (KJV - emphasis mine)

How is it that in light of John 5:26, the Father has "everlasting life" in Himself that has to be GIVEN (greek: edoken - other translations also say GRANTED) to the Son, so that the Son has that life in himself?
The type of life being talked about in John 5:26 is "everlasting life" (verse 24). So God the Father has this eternal life in Himself inherently, because he has no beginning and thus must have it inherently in Himself, otherwise He would not have been able to live for eternity past. Nobody gave the Father this life - he inherently has it in Himself!
The Athanasian Creed says:

"The Father eternal; the Son eternal; and the Holy Ghost eternal. And
yet they are not three eternals; but one eternal. So likewise the
Father is Almighty; the Son Almighty; and the Holy Ghost Almighty...
The Father is made of none; neither created, nor begotten. The Son is
of the Father alone; not made, nor created; but begotten. The Holy
Ghost is of the Father and of the Son; neither made, nor created, nor
begotten; but proceeding...
And in this Trinity none is before, or after another; none is
greater, or less than another. But the whole three Persons are
coeternal, and coequal."

It is hence clear that, according to the Chalcedonian Creeds, the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit share the same essence of being, the same nature.
In order to be an eternal living being (past, present and future), as God Almighty is, you have to have life in yourself, always. If you have to be GIVEN or GRANTED that life, it means you didn't have it. Life itself (being alive) is an inherent part of the nature of a living being!
According to Philipp Schaff who analyzed the works of St. Augustin, John 5:26 is explained as follows in the light of the Trinity:

For it is not, as with the creature so with the Son of God before the
incarnation and before He took upon Him our flesh, the Only-begotten
by whom all things were made; that He is one thing, and has another:
but He is in such way as to be what He has. And this is said more
plainly, if any one is fit to receive it, in that place where He says:
“For as the Father hath life in Himself, so hath He given to the Son
to have life in Himself.”[John 5:26] For He did not give to Him,
already existing and not having life, that He should have life in
Himself; inasmuch as, in that He is, He is life. Therefore “He gave to
the Son to have life in Himself” means, He begat the Son to be
unchangeable life, which is life eternal"

Put in simpler terms: God the Father gave the Son life in Himself, which is life eternal. It means that the Son is eternal life, because what he has been given is what he became - it has become part of his essence!
God the Father is the cause and the source of life. All Christian denominations I know of, that believe in the creation by God agree to this.
How can it be maintained that Jesus shares the same divine essence with the Father, but had to be GIVEN "everlasting life" that was never given to the Father, who apparently inherently had it in Himself, whereas it had to be GRANTED/GIVEN to Jesus (the Son)?
The act of the Father having granted and/or given (greek: ἔδωκεν) Jesus eternal life in Himself, is an act that has temporal implications - in the 68 occurrences of this form of the verb "edoken" in the Aorist Indicative Active, which expresses the simple occurrence of an action in past time, none appear atemporal/eternal - which means that there was a point in time where Jesus did NOT have this type of life in Himself, which would mean that he does not share exactly the same essence with God.
How do Trinitarians explain this apparent contradiction?

This question is fully answered by the first answer (8 up-votes) to the (related or duplicate) question which this question mentions. The begotten Son received (and receives) life from the Father in an eternal begetting. What more does the question expect to be stated ? Either this doctrine is received and believed . . . . .  or it is not. It is clear that the question has not grasped the concept. But to claim a contradiction where none exists is not going to assist in the perceiving of a spiritual and eternal concept.

This question is similar to: How do Trinitarians explain the Father granting life to the Son (John 5:26)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NigelJ I've edited the first paragraph to make it clearer. You said: "The begotten Son received (and receives) life from the Father in an eternal begetting" - What is the exegetical biblical basis for this?
I've provided a textual and grammatical analysis here, based on which, yes I see a clear contradiction between the biblical text and to the homoousian argument as understood by the trinitarian creeds.

But you have not grasped the essence of the doctrine - that Father and Son through One Holy Spirit . . . . . . . have a relationship in Divine Unity. This is Divine Life and this is the eternal state of a divine begetting. If eternal life is given then there never was a time when it was not given. There is - no contradiction.

@NigelJ - that may sound rational in your own mind, but with all due respect, I think it's non-sense. The act of "giving" is always temporal - even if it is continuous towards an eternal future. "Giving", by definition denotes to the pass of something to someone, that wasn't possessed by that someone before it was given. It is always temporal - I've linked 68 occurrences of the word used in the bible - not one is atemporal. Also tell me of one single instance of begetting (and the bible used the term a lot) where begetting did not denote a beginning of existence.

The single instance is the only begotten of the Father. Quod erat demonstrandum.

Luke 8:42 - the Father has a an only begotten (monogenes) daughter - does that mean that this only begotten daughter has the same age than her Father that begot her? Similarly Luke 9:38 - only begotten (monogenes) son. Did the only begotten Son begin to live when his Father was born? Probavi te malum

@NigelJ I also see the first response, however it is based on two other reasonings. (The two quoted creeds) I believe the question here is attempting to obtain a more detailed response than just "well two seperate groups of people agreed and said" It does make answering the question more difficult, but that is the purpose of the site is it not? At the OP, based on some of your stances I believe many of the answers will be contrary to your own belief, but this is not truly an issue. I've done similar things with questions to the LDS. You will have to accept the answers :)

I will of course accept answers (even if I don't agree with it) - the current top answer (saying John 5:26 it is not about ontological relationship) I can even agree with albeit it is written by someone with a trinitarian background. - I don't think John 5:26 was an ontological statement per se, the subject was judgement and eternal life. It seems to me that the implications that this statement imposes though as to the essence of being of God are either accepted as mystery or straight ignored.

Before you convince yourself that you can comfortably "explain away" the large majority understandings of Christ, you may wish to practice on Philippians 2 and Colossians 1. John's gospel is probably best walked on by on the other side'd.

Are you trying to solve all contradictions in the Bible?

"it is written by someone with a trinitarian background" - which is exactly what your question asked for...

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I think they're trying to prove that Jehovah's Witnesses have the only correct beliefs.

@OrangeDog - 1) I'm not a "they" but a single person - 2) I don't need to prove anything, as I'm not the judge of right or wrong - I leave that to God.
I just like asking Trinitarians tricky questions ;-) which will hopefully have the effect of: they question their viewpoint and do further research and eventually come to a stronger belief - resulting in a stronger faith - whatever that belief/faith may be. Isn't that the whole point behind "Iron sharpens Iron"?

@JsWitness fortunately, "they" has functioned as a singular pronoun for 700 years.

@OrangeDog - Well, I did a little research and you are right about the singular use of "they" - note: English is not my native tongue! Thanks for sharing a minor but good new insight :-)

@OrangeDog "They" is used as singular when the number is unspecified:  "If anyone has a question let them ask it now".  When a single person is in view, "they" is not appropriate.

@MikeBorden it is 100% appropriate. Native English speakers use it without even noticing. "If a single person has a question, let them ask it now".

@OrangeDog "If a single person has a question, you can ask it now."  In my experience, lots of Native English speakers speak wrong. :)

@MikeBorden https://www.oed.com/discover/a-brief-history-of-singular-they

@OrangeDog The very first and earliest example in this article "Each man hurried . . . till they drew near..." is just what I mean.  "Each man" indicates multiple people, albeit one at a time, therefore it is not a singular "they" since it is referring to the un-numbered collection of "each man".

@MikeBorden I'm afraid your understanding of English is lacking. Now, why has this comment section turned into multiple arguments about grammar? At least the first person admitted they were wrong.

@OrangeDog "Each man hurried until they (all) drew near".  Without any lack this is the intended meaning (in fact, it is being very clearly said) and not wrong at all.  In our current day and age of sound-bytes I'm afraid careful reading and comprehension is becoming a thing of the past.  I am finished making the point.

Remember that for Trinitarians, the Chalcedonian understanding of the dual natures of Christ is "part of the same package".  In Trinitarian theology, the terminology "Son of God" has to refer to this one person with two natures: the divine nature is "eternally begotten", but the human nature was born physically (in time) like we were.
God in His divine nature cannot die, but the Word in his human nature can die.  And it's God who raised the Word's human nature from the dead.  Similarly, the Word's life in His human nature started at the virginal conception in the womb of Mary.
Therefore, when Jesus spoke about "death", "life", and "eternal life" in John 5:24-29, Jesus referred NOT to his divine nature who cannot die (the Word's eternal generation from the Father), but to his and to our human nature:

v. 24 : The Trinitarian God wills to send the Word into the world by adding a human nature to be born and to be believed, who was crucified, died, buried, and resurrected to life.  So when we unite ourselves with Jesus (second Adam) in baptism, we can also be resurrected to eternal life.
v. 25-27 : The "Son of God" here is the human nature of the Word, who preached the gospel of life.  God (who possesses eternal life) has granted Jesus (in his human nature) eternal life merited to his perfect sacrifice on the cross.  The glorified human nature of Christ lives forever in heaven right now, waiting for us as the Bridegroom of the Church so that one day we will be with Christ (as he was with his disciples when he was on earth).  Jesus (in his human nature) also merited the right to pass judgment (as the Son of Man).  When we pass the Day of Judgment after our death, we too will receive eternal life in a glorified body just like Jesus, the first to be resurrected in this manner.  That is our hope in Christ.

Answering your questions more directly

How can it be maintained that Jesus shares the same divine essence with the Father, but had to be GIVEN "everlasting life" that was never given to the Father, who apparently inherently had it in Himself, whereas it had to be GRANTED/GIVEN to Jesus (the Son)?

The Father, The Word, and The Holy Spirit is one being from outside space/time sharing the same Trinitarian "life" referred to the phrase in v. 26 "the Father has life in himself".  This "life" does NOT need to be given / granted to the Word, since "himself" refers to the same divine, immaterial being (the One God).
Remember that Trinity as a concept is for our benefit in understanding the otherwise hidden God, so the Three "Person" in this Being is only analogy, not equal to our concept of a human person.  One strand in Trinitarian theology is Aquinas's conception of this Trinitarian Person as "subsistent relation", where we understand the Father as eternal paternity (a relation), the Word as eternally begotten (another relation), and the Holy Spirit as Love spirated between the two "Person"  (another relation).  Only the "Person" of the Word obtains flesh, as John 1 pointed out, and as a subsistent relation of a Single Being, there is only one divine life that does NOT have to be given to granted to the other 2 relations.
But as I pointed above, the human nature (the flesh) of the Word is another matter, because it is a temporal effect, so there is a history of this flesh.  The Incarnation started in the womb of Mary; so this human life started at that time.  This human life died after about 33 years old at the cross, and 3 days later this flesh was resurrected to "eternal life", so Jesus's post resurrection life continues through 2,000 years so far and will continue into the new heaven and new earth.  Only God can give that kind of eternity to a human flesh, and this is what John 5:26 talks about "granted to the Son to have life in himself", the "Son" interpreted as the Word's human nature.

The act of the Father having granted and/or given (greek: ἔδωκεν) Jesus eternal life in Himself, is an act that has temporal implications - in the 68 occurrences of this form of the verb "edoken" in the Aorist Indicative Active, which expresses the simple occurrence of an action in past time, none appear atemporal/eternal - which means that there was a point in time where Jesus did NOT have this type of life in Himself, which would mean that he does not share exactly the same essence with God.

The Trinitarian understanding above is consistent with the Greek grammar you alluded above, because the Word's flesh IS temporal.  So yes, there was a point where the Word did not have flesh, the period of human history before Mary was born, or more precisely before the divine conception in Mary's womb.
Trinitarians think this way of separating the 2 natures of Christ is the most consistent with all the data in the Bible:

the Word's divine natures share the same essence with the Father's divine nature (being simply subsistent relations of the same being)
the Word's human nature shares the same properties with any human being, including having a history, but only without sin


The type of life Jesus is talking about in John 5:26 is „eternal life“, and not „flesh“ as is clearly evident from the immediate context. Jesus was raised as a „life-giving“ or „quickening“ spirit at his resurrection. There is no indication whatsoever in the Bible that Jesus was „given life in himself“ in his human nature only.

@JsWitness  but trinitarians maintain that the duality of Jesus was not strictly separate. He was born as God/Human which is why the majority of the church respects Mary as the first Christian and the Orthodox church calls her Theotokos (God-bearer). So that continues onwards until the death, resurrection, and afterwards.  Doesn't answer the main question, but just your comment here.

@JsWitness You said: "There is no indication whatsoever ... his human nature only." This is where we disagree. I trust Thomist Trinitarian reading of John which (unlike NigelJ's) emphasizes the humanity of Jesus as the exclusive "interface" to God (John 14:6). Having been GIVEN eternal life to POSSESS "in himself" (v26) and the AUTHORITY to give it on judgment day (v27), he can truthfully say "I am the resurrection and the life" (John 11:25-27).  On that day, Jesus in the flesh will meet us, judge us, and grant the righteous eternal life. I think that's a defensible reading.

@JsWitness So I also agree with the third interpretation of the article Paul Chernoch cited that v26 is emphatically NOT about eternal generation.  The whole passage context (vv. 19-30) is about the flesh's mind and will (separate than his divine mind and will).  BUT I think Aquinas goes a lot further than evangelicals to read that almost the whole of John's gospel is about the Son of God in the flesh, including eating the flesh of Jesus that contains life (John 6:35).

@GratefulDisciple - Giving this empathetic consideration, I have to say, that in light of the trinitarian dogma, how I understand it, as well as the dual nature of Christ, this answer makes the most sense out of the answers received so far. This is why your answer receives my upvote :-) - That being said, you'd need to ignore the implications of 1 Corinthians 15:45, and that the dual nature of Christ is nowhere taught in the Bible.

@JsWitness Thanks.  I still want to update this answer with my comments in the chat after summarizing them.  With regards to 1 Cor 15:45, it makes sense to be included in this Q, but considering there are many answers already, it may be too late to include it in the OP, so better ask another question.

The OP makes an incorrect assumption of what Jesus said.
John 5 (ESV)

24 Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into judgment, but has passed from death to life.


25 “Truly, truly, I say to you, an hour is coming, and is now here, when the dead will hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who hear will live. 26 For as the Father has life in himself, so he has granted the Son also to have life in himself.

Eternal life, or everlasting life is what those who believe have. The term eternal life is unnecessary with the Father since life the Father has in Himself is life with no beginning or end.
When Jesus says He has the same life in Himself, it’s just another way of saying “I and the Father are one.”
When the dead “hear my word and believe” they will have something they previously lacked, life which doesn't end.

I make no assumptions - I just stated Jesus' words as he said them. The literal translation reads "As for the Father has life in himself so also to the Son He gave life to have in himself." - there is no reference by Jesus as to "I and the Father are one" in this whole passage/discussion with the Jews. Jesus received from the Father the same life that the Father has in himself inherently (nobody gave it to the Father) - that's what Jesus clearly said.

@JsWitness You say, "How is it that in light of John 5:26, the Father has "everlasting life" in Himself that has to be GIVEN (greek: edoken - other translations also say GRANTED) to the Son, so that the Son has that life in himself?"

What type of "life" to you think Jesus referred to in John 5:26 - the immediate context talks about "everlasting/eternal life" (John 5:24) - verse 25 talks about the resurrection - about "those who hear will live" - what kind of life will they have after their resurrection? "Eternal life". It's self-sustaining eternal life - Jesus didn't already have it - it had to be given to him by the Father. Nobody gave it to the Father - it has always been part of his essence of being.

@JsWitness Jesus used the term everlasting life with those who were dead. Like all people everlasting life means life which has a beginning but will have no end. Life as used with the Father is life which has no beginning or end. You need to stick to the text. The Father has life; the believer may have everlasting life. The difference? One has no beginning or end: the other has a beginning and no end.

The fact of the matter is that Jesus said that it had to be GIVEN to him by the Father - whether that  was in time or outside of time is not my core argument - that it was GIVEN has to mean that it was ADDED to Jesus‘ original essence of being - whereas nobody gave it to the Father, he already had it.

@JsWitness 1. When Jesus said “I and the Father are one” He was in a body and the Father was not. Despite an obvious difference they were still one. This tells us that differences do not determine what it is that makes them one. Or stated another way, oneness is not “undone” by differences. I submit the most significant aspect of the Father is life. Therefore if the Son has the Father’s life in Himself they are one in the most significant way. One issue with your approach is trying to find a way to turn the most significant aspect of oneness into something which denies oneness. I’m certain…

…no one listening to Jesus’ words would look for ways to understand them as saying He was not equal to God/Father as you are trying to do. I doubt the Jews would use your approach to absolve Jesus from a charge of blasphemy. 2. There is no time stated when this occurred. A simple way to resolve the potential conflict is to recognize it happened after He was born, at the baptism for example. The Father is giving life in Himself to Jesus despite the fact Jesus has a physical body. Or perhaps it was at His birth. Regardless, you need to see this in the light of oneness, not differences.


„Holy Father, keep through thine own name those whom thou hast given me, that they may be one, as we are … That they all may be one; as thou, Father, art in me, and I in thee, that they also may be one in us: that the world may believe that thou hast sent me.“ John 17:11, 21 - Are Christians included in the Oneness you are talking about? The Oneness is in unity and purpose- not in essence! The life that the Father has is an essential part of his essence, and that same life that the Father had (non-human btw) had to be given to the Son - hence they are not of the same essence!


Also thanks for admitting that you presume the Trinity when reading the text - „no one listening to Jesus’ words would look for ways to understand them as saying He was not equal to God/Father“ - clearly meaning that you automatically read the trinity into the text. There is no time component required for when exactly this happened. It cannot have been given to Jesus‘ human nature, because his human nature died - the life that the Father has in himself can‘t die, can it?

@JsWitness No problem. “This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.” John 5:18. I understand what He says as does John and the Jews. And I maintain no one making that accusation would interpret what He says as you do, that He is not claiming equality with God. If only JWs had been present to explain to the Jews how they were not understanding Jesus as saying He was equal with God, maybe the crucifixion could have been prevented.

John 5:18 just proclaims what the Jews Jesus was conversing with thought. Do you also think Jesus broke the Sabbath? You think they were right? What was Jesus‘ response? „Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do: for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise.“ (John 5:19) Does that sound like equality to you? We have a time component here again - there is no synchronicity in the Son‘s works with the Father‘s - Jesus watches his Father do, and then repeats the same thing „likewise“ (homoiós: likewise, in like manner)

@JsWitness John as the narrator gave the reasons they wanted to kill Jesus. I don't think he was being untruthful. And he never once said they were wrong. Instead he kept giving one example after another. Obviously you have a different opinion.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are many views of what is meant by John 5:26.

Proof that Christ is not eternal, because the gift occurred at some point in time and it is an ontological gift, so before the gift, Christ did not have :life in himself", so was either less than divine or did not even exist yet.
An ontological expression of eternal generation, a gift given throughout all eternity, so that there was never any time when Christ was not given this "life in himself".
A matter of economy or function is indicated. The Son was granted the authority to give life to others. It occurred in time, but did not bring about a change in the Son's existence or essence, but in his authority.

I personally do not know whether it is the economic trinity or the ontological trinity that is in view, but this article proposes that it is the economic trinity:
https://dbts.edu/2019/03/11/is-christs-receipt-of-life-in-himself-john-526-proof-of-eternal-generation/
Here is a quote from the article:

There are basically three possible interpretations of this verse. The
first, which Carson bills as “ditheistic” (we might even say Arian),
sees the Father as bestowing independent life or aseity on Christ at
some point in time, thus rendering him God within history. That is,
Christ was at one point not God (he was created, perhaps) and then
became a separate God. We will not be considering this view as a
legitimate option. I mention it, though, because a careless proponence
of eternal generation can sometimes lead to this error.
A second view sees the Father as eternally bestowing independent life
or aseity upon the Son, in Carson’s words, as an “eternal grant”
(a.k.a. eternal generation). By arguing thus, the Son is ontologically
“of the Father,” begotten or generated by him, yet not created or
made. The rubric “begotten not made” (or some close equivalent) has
been a part of the Christian tradition since the 3rd century, and has
appeared in nearly every major creed since Nicaea. This rubric was a
hedge against Arianism and is considered part of the orthodox
tradition. By it the three persons of the Godhead are presented as
wholly and eternally God, equal in essence and authority.
A third view argues that this passage does not speak at all to
ontological relationships within the Trinity, but rather to matters of
economy or function. It sees the Father bestowing on the Son the
privilege of granting life to whomever he is pleased to give it. The
NLT projects this interpretation in its translation: “The Father has
life in himself, and he has granted that same life-giving power to his
Son.” As such, the Father is granting the Son functional authority to
grant life, just as he grants him the functional authority to judge in
verse 27.

The author then goes on to argue for the third possibility.

I checked the Blog article - so the argument of the Blog writer for what is said by Jesus in John 5:26 is not for homoousia at all, but for the granting of authority.
I wonder why He did not even consider the "Arian" view, and denied it of the bat.
Well, the issue I see is this (even with the 3rd view). The authority to judge and to bestow eternal life was given to Jesus at his resurrection. He "was made a life-giving spirit" is what Paul said (1 Cor 15:45) - the Father had this power in Himself, and gave it to Jesus at resurrection - that doesn't sound like eternal co-equality to me.

@JsWitness I think it is not unusual for someone to not consider the Arian perspective considering it is considered heresy by most christian denominations.

I don't consider myself "Arian" - I disagree with a few aspects for Arius' Christology, and beyond that, there is quite a bit of his teachings that I don't subscribe to. Dismissing his Christology completely though, based on him being branded as a "heretic" by his contemporaries, while most of his writings have been destroyed, does not inspire a lot of trust in the writer's "unbiased" analysis.

@JsWitness  Of Arius it was written, "Certainly he was the Seventh Star of Rev. 1:20; 3:14" in the JW book 'The Finished Mystery' p.64, with a drawing of 7 frames; St. Paul at the top, then St. John, then Arius, then Waldo, then Wycliffe, then Luther, then Russell. I suppose you also don't subscribe to quite a bit of the teachings of Waldo, Wycliffe, Luther and Russell either? Well, it's not necessary to agree with everything any of those men taught to be seen as a follower of their main theological teachings. JWs are identified with Arius whether they like that or not.

"I suppose you also don't subscribe to quite a bit of the teachings of Waldo, Wycliffe, Luther and Russell either?" - I don't subscribe to them, indeed - I wouldn't like to be called "Russelite". If I were their contemporary (without internet and bible tools access) I might have - I don't know. JWs are certainly closer to Arius than to Athanasius - but I guess you would not be all happy to be called "Athanasian" or "Constantinian" either, would you? Arius btw. didn't like/appreciate proponents of his Christology being called after him. He never considered people that agreed with him "Arians".

@JsWitness  I gladly identify with being a Protestant Christian, which I know you do not. If you want to face up to how essentially 'Arian' JWs are, see my answer to this recent Q.  If I am wrong about that essential point of agreement with Arius, please correct me. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103315/how-does-a-trinitarian-explain-the-role-each-person-of-the-trinity-plays-in-t

@Anne One crucial peace is missing - In one of the few writings of Arius that has survived, he claims that God is beyond comprehension, even for the Son. Historian H. M. Gwatkin states in his book The Arian Controversy: “The God of Arius is an unknown God, whose being is hidden in eternal mystery. No creature can reveal him, and he cannot reveal himself.” JWs worship neither the “incomprehensible” God of the Trinitarians nor the “unknown God” of Arius. They say, with the apostle Paul: “There is actually to us one God the Father, out of whom all things are.”​—1 Corinthians 8:6.

@JsWitness  Unitarians say the same thing re. 1 Cor.8:6. Do JWs say their God is fully knowable; that they have explained their God as has the creature, Jesus, and their explanation is sensible while the trinity doctrine is nonsense? But never mind where you say JWs disagree with Arius - I flagged up the unarguable, fundamental agreement with him. Where am I wrong about that, please?

For as the Father has life in Himself (from everlasting to everlasting and inherently) so hath He given...
Whatever kind and duration of life the Father has, that is the kind and duration of life that the Son has.  A limitation of one and not the other cannot be entertained.
The Son is Logos and that is not only the word spoken but the rational mind behind the word.  Therefore, if one can imagine a point before which the Father existed but had no rational mind then we can say Logos had a beginning.

If you share the same essence with the One who inherently has life in Himself, and that life is part of His essence of being, and you, sharing exactly the same essence - Why would you need to be given it in the first place? Jesus didn’t say „For as the Father has life in himself, I have life in myself“ - he emphasized that it was given. You only can be „given“ something, if you didn’t habe it before it was given. There is no single instance in the whole bible where that‘s not the case.

Mike, I agree with where you went. But I'm not happy with how you got there. If that makes sense.

@JsWitness Three things:  1) How can there be another instance in the Bible regarding God's one and only begotten Son?.  2) the adverb ωσπερ (hosper), rendered "as" meaning wholly as, entirely like.  3) The verb in question (to give) is in the Aorist tense in this verse, which is deliberately silent about when the action takes place and how long it lasts.  We have to be careful about assigning temporal qualities to a non-temporal God.  We cannot give from everlasting to everlasting but God can.

@JsWitness "You only can be „given“ something, if you didn’t have it before it was given."  What if you inhabit eternity and there is no before?

@MikeBorden - Very simple - then I inherently have it and don't have to be given it

@MikeBorden - "1) How can there be another instance in the Bible regarding God's one and only begotten Son?" - Nobody says that Jesus isn't unique! He's begotten though and he is the only Son at that. Words have meaning. The Bible makes clear what begotten means and how it should be understood (Matthew 1:1-16 among many other...). The Bible makes clear what it means to be the firstborn many, many times, and how the firstborn is revered. The Bible also makes clear what only begotten (monogenes) means. And guess what: it never means having the same age than the Father!

"2) the adverb ωσπερ (hosper), rendered "as" meaning wholly as, entirely like." - Yep, but from a starting point - from the point in time it had been GIVEN

"3) The verb in question (to give) is in the Aorist tense in this verse, which is deliberately silent about when the action takes place and how long it lasts. We have to be careful about assigning temporal qualities to a non-temporal God. We cannot give from everlasting to everlasting but God can." - So you say I should not take Jesus at his word, and the verbiage he used - especially as the same verbform is used 68 times in the NT, that always have temporal implications? I'm sorry, I won't do that.

@JsWitness Eternity is not an infinity of time.  There is no before and after in eternity that is how "given life" does not require a state beforehand when life had not yet been given.  It is life "entirely like" the life the Father has:  Without beginning or end.  Jesus is given life in Himself that has no beginning.  If a word is used in regards to temporal things then of course it has temporal implications.

Let's avoid temporal implications for a moment - it won't get us anywhere as we will most probably not agree on this point - the fact of the matter is that Jesus does not inherently have life in himself in terms of his original essence of being - otherwise it didn't need to be given (independent of when it was given). Hence John 5:26 shows that "everlasting life" was added to Jesus' original essence. This life was already part of the Fathers essence (nobody gave it to him), which is why I argue that the Father and the Son are not of the same essence originally.

@JsWitness The fact of the matter is that Logos does have life inherently in his original essence because the life he has is exactly the same as the Father's life.  That's what Jesus said:  "As the Father has life in Himself so hath He given...".  If we focus on the "given" but not the "as" we run past the truth.

@MikeBorden - the "as" you're referring to, is in regards to the authority/power bestowed upon Jesus to give "everlasting life" to faithful Christians (verse 25). The same power that God has to give life has been given to the Son as well so that He can give life! Anything else doesn't make sense (even if you'd prefer it to be that way), because then why did Jesus say it was GIVEN to him? As already stated - for Jesus to say what you want him to say, he would have needed to say „For as the Father has life in himself, I have life in myself“ - but that's not what He said!

@JsWitness The life and the authority are separate in the text.  'As' equates the two 'lifes'.  Because there has never been a 'time' when Jesus was not given that same life that the Father has.  It is an eternal giving and not a temporal giving.  I don't think we're going to see eye to eye on this but we can go into a chat room if you'd like.

Philippians 2:7 (NLT):

Instead, he gave up his divine privileges;
he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being.

Three simple things happened:

For his incarnation, Christ became a mortal physical being.
When he was executed, he lost his mortal life, and was dead, buried, and unconscious.
When he was resurrected, God the Father gave him immortal life.

Why do people see a problem with this?

I have a very hard time fitting this explanation into the context of John 5. Some would also see it as being on the boundary of orthodoxy, though this might just be an issue of phrasing - it suggests a conflict with the doctrine of the incarnate Christ having both a human nature and an immortal divine nature.

@user111403, the complications are caused by doctrines holding that the physical Jesus was still immortal despite having given up his "divine privileges".

@Ray the challenge is, "God gave Him immortal life". Christ = God = Christ raised Himself??? Rev 7 16-  tells us Christ currently sits in the middle of the throne obviously so I have no problem with this but others might. Perhaps elaborate a little?

Sorry Rev 7.15 (not 16)

@adam, Revelation 7:15 is a vision from the future (14 says it is after the tribulation), not  from 2000 years ago. ¶ If Jesus gave up his divine privileges, then he couldn't raise himself (especially if he were dead, buried, and unconscious). That was something the Father had to do.

@RayButterworth - if Jesus gave up His divine privileges, He couldn't raise Himself - and yet in John 10:17-18 He claims exactly that. If we agree that He gave up some of His "divine privileges" but kept His divine nature, I'd definitely argue that immortality is part of the nature rather than a "privilege".

@user111403 says "He couldn't raise Himself - and yet in John 10:17-18 He claims exactly that." — It says "I lay down my life, that I might take it again". I.e. He willingly allows himself to be killed in order to take life when the Father gives it to him. He couldn't take that new life if he weren't dead.

@RayButterworth Jesus doesn't say "I lay down my life, and my Father will give me life". He says "I have power to lay it down, and I have power to take it again". Jesus clearly claims for Himself the power to give Himself life. To be honest I don't really see why this is a problematic concept. After all we also have a soul that doesn't just disappear when we die. Obviously our soul can't bring our body back to life and return to it, but then we aren't God.

I thought of this verse as well, but I think the argument is a bit simple. It would be interesting to go into more detail about how Jesus took up the role of servant instead of master. And how these two roles interact.

@user111403 says "we also have a soul" — No, we don''t have souls, we are souls. See my answer to Jesus' Soul and Spirit?. ¶ "the power to give Himself life" — That is one translation. The original Greek word (G1849) has a primary meaning of permission or authority. E.g. YLT: "authority I have again to take it"; NIV: "authority to take it up again"; NASB20: "I have authority to take it back"; many others.

@RayButterworth as I understand you're saying that the soul and the body are the same? I would tend to disagree (though it's not something I've studied in depth), but accepting for the sake of argument, then I say we have spirits and the point stands. We have consciousness after death. As to the second part, "I have authority" just as much as "I have power" implies an active participant, not a passive recipient.

@user111403 says "We have consciousness after death" — yet Ecclesiastes 9:5 states: "the dead know nothing" and Psalms 146:4 says "… he returneth to his earth; in that very day his thoughts perish" —
See my answers to …arguments against the doctrine of Intercession of Saints? and … soul sleep …

Knowing a little more of what you are asking, I will attempt to give it a proper response. I apologize in advance for how much this response will address the question vs how much it will address the fundamental premise of the question. My answer might ramble and be a bit messy.
Standard part of my answers: My perspective will be of the Orthodox Church perspective as much as I am able to explain. This church is "Trinitarian" and my belief is also of that.
My church uses Biblical and Tradition as sources, this might be evident below.

"Always be prepared to make a defense to anyone who calls you to account for the hope that is in you, yet do it with gentleness and reverence." (1 Peter 3:15)

I will gently point out here that your interpretation is considered heresy. (It is a form of Arianism/Nestorianism) And it has been condemned by the original church and every mainstream church that followed after schism occurred.

From my understanding you see an issue with the fact that the verse says specifically that Jesus was given "LIFE" from the Father.
This for you an issue that would refute the eternal aspect of Christ, because you see a temporal action where the Father is giving Christ "LIFE"

There are many interpretations of this verse.

The Father as bestowing independent life or aseity on Christ at some point in time, thus rendering him God within history. (Arianism - Note that this is your interpretation as well)

The Father as eternally bestowing independent life or aseity upon the Son. (Eternal Generation)

The Father bestowing on the Son the privilege of granting life to whomever he is pleased to give it. (Economy/Function)


While looking through Bible Hermeneutics I found this which indirectly gave me some info as well.

Those who understand it as to the Divine nature, say, that this phrase, hath life in himself, is expressive of the name Jehovah; and that Christ is proved to be the true Jehovah by what is here said, that he hath life in himself. ... (Matthew Poole's Commentary).

So this gives us a 4th interpretation here...

This is another way to say "I am God"


There is a lightweight explanation of course. It is an eternal incomprehensible being "squished" into a mortal brain is explaining the greater form to us little mortal people with mortal understanding.
Just as in flatland, the sphere couldn't not explain the concept of "up" even though it tried by doing "miracles" (teleporting, disappearing from the plane, etc)
So technically a 5th interpretation exists: We are trying to understand something incomprehensible.

1st answer
Ultimately at this point your question is answered. "How do trinitarians resolve...this?" They resolve it by using one of the interpretations that weren't deemed to be heresy during the period of the early church.
That is to say, they will simply use one of the other 4+ interpretations.

Now as seen in the other similar question you linked, this issue is clearly answered by 2 symbols of faith (two creeds).

“I believe . . . . and in one Lord, Jesus Christ, the Only-begotten Son of God, begotten of the Father before all ages. Light of light, true God from true God, begotten, not made, one in essence with the Father, from Whom all things were made.”

"Begotten of the Father before all ages" this is affirmed by the writing of St. John.

“In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with God and the Word was God.” (Beginning of the book of John)

In this way he calls the Son and the Word of God, God. He further informs us that the Son and Word of God existed from the Beginning, that is, before Creation, before Time. He always existed, together with the Father. He was and is inseparable from God the Father. And He is Perfectly God.
St. Paul complements this by saying,

“Great is the mystery of godliness–God appeared in the flesh.” (1 Timothy 3:16)

How? By the Incarnation of the Second Person of the Holy Trinity, the Son, Jesus Christ. Elsewhere, St. Paul calls Christ Lord and God, Great God, Blessed God. But first St. Thomas, after Christ’s Resurrection, had called Christ, “My Lord and my God.”

Now another issue I see here is "Why is this 1 passage more significant than any other passage?" Why should this one verse be treated differently? We should look to other verses as well.
In other places in Holy Scripture, the same Divine attributes are ascribed to Christ that are also ascribed to the Father. With language that is unable to be considered dubious or ambiguous. He is called The One Who Existed Before All Time, the All-mighty, the All-Knowing, Equal to the Father, Creator of the World.

Some examples are... Matthew 1:23, Mark 2:5-7, John 1:1, John 1:14, John 5:18, John 5:23, John 10:30, John 20:27-29, Philippians 2:5-7, Philippians 2:10-11 (see Isaiah 45:23), Philippians 3:20-21, Colossians 1:15, Colossians 2:2-3, Colossians 2:9, Ephesians 1:22-23, Hebrews 1:3, Hebrews 1:6, ... (1 Samuel 2:10; Psalm 50:6; Ecclesiastes 12:14; many others). All refer to God alone is Judge, but these are specifically also for Jesus (John 5:22, 27; 9:39; Acts 10:42; 2 Timothy 4:1). So again Jesus is God. ... there are many more verses...


Christ Himself teaches that “All must honour and worship the Son as they do the Father. He who does not revere the Son, does not revere the Father.” (John 5:23) In other words, he who denies the divinity of the Son, denies the divinity of the Father. They are a package deal, so to speak.

This part might be more off topic, as it addresses a fundamental assumption underneath the question. That is, the OP has the #1 interpretation I mentioned above. (Arianism/Nestorianism style of interpretation)
For example, using this style of interpretation when Jesus says “My Father is greater than I.” (John, passage about The Lord's supper) would be understood, in a literal sense. Even though as a human Jesus is clearly "lesser" in glory at that moment.

But what of that one word you were so focused on?
"Given" or "Granted", to answer this I'll go into the Orthodox understanding of the Trinity. I'll refer to Fr. Stephen thoughts on the matter. (a retired Archpriest of the Orthodox Church in America, Pastor Emeritus of St. Anne Orthodox Church in Oak Ridge, Tennessee.)
The Trinity has its source (πηγή) in the Father.  We should understand this not only as a matter of Trinitarian thought, but as the proper grounding of the spiritual life as well. To be a Christian in the proper sense, to worship God as Father, Son and Holy Spirit, is to acknowledge that our life does not have its source in ourselves, but in God.
Christ, particularly in St. John’s gospel, makes frequent reference to the Father as the origin and source of all that He has and does:

Then Jesus answered and said to them, “Most assuredly, I say to you, the Son can do nothing of Himself, but what He sees the Father do; for whatever He does, the Son also does in like manner. For the Father loves the Son, and shows Him all things that He Himself does; and He will show Him greater works than these, that you may marvel. For as the Father raises the dead and gives life to them, even so the Son gives life to whom He will…. For as the Father has life in Himself, so He has granted the Son to have life in Himself… (John 5:19-21 and 26)

Fr. Stephen thoughts...

The dynamic of the relationship between the Father and the Son
described by Christ is also a dynamic that lies at the very heart of
authentic existence. It is a dynamic that seems quite foreign in our
cultural context. The modern world is a culture of “fatherless
children” (sometimes quite literally). The past (and thus the place
and source of our origins) is always seen as something to be overcome.
The notion of “progress” includes a forgetting of the past and the
reduction of its power in our lives. We seek to self-create and
self-define our lives as though we had no source outside of ourselves.
Orthodoxy makes frequent mention of the “Church Fathers.” For many,
the phrase is simply seen as another set of authoritative ideas. As
such, in true modern form, we seek to appropriate for ourselves (and
on our own terms), what we choose and prefer within their writings,
and then imagine that they have authority in our lives. But this
misses the dynamic that “Church Fathers” is meant to convey. For like
Christ’s reference to God the Father (“the Son can do nothing of
Himself”), so the Church makes reference to those who have gone
before. The Christian faith is always “that which is received,” and
not “that which is chosen.” And this receiving is dynamic and living,
a present action within the life of the Church and no mere
acknowledgement of history’s importance.
It is a dynamic that all too easily feels like tyranny to the modern
mind. Modernity equates liberty with the freedom to decide and choose,
to define ourselves and the world around us. In the words of Justice
Anthony Kennedy (Planned Parenthood vs. Casey, 1992):

At the heart of liberty is the right to define one’s own concept of
existence, of meaning, of the universe, and of the mystery of human
life.


You will note that the subject shifts towards God as Fr Stephan wrote/spoke.

Nothing is as difficult as true theology. Simply saying something correct is beside the point. Correctness does not rise to the level of theology. Theology, rightly done, is a path towards union with God. It is absolutely more than an academic exercise. Theology is not the recitation of correct facts, it is the apprehension and statement of Beauty.


Theology looks for the words, in the right relationship, in the right order, at the right time. Written, spoken, sung, carved, inscribed, printed or lighting a digital screen, they share and commune the relationship, in the right order, at the right time to the right one. Sometimes a single word suffices.

From this we can understand that there is a contrary version, it is quite possible to present "anti-Theology" that is to say. We can use the correct words in a way that does not guide us towards God.

I always feel like at the end of long answers that I've missed something, I might edit things and add things.

"I always feel like at the end of long answers that I've missed something" — I'm not speaking specifically about this answer, but in general when I'm in that situation I usually find that the problem is that I've actually said too much, and rather than adding more I end up deleting the non-essential parts.

So if I read the 3 interpretations (next to Nr. 1 which you dismiss as Arian heresy), none of them addresses my argument, as ultimately they all say that Jesus was not sharing the same essence of being with the Father, before the Father gave Jesus "life in himself". All your interpretations are saying is that the sharing of a part of the divine essence ("life in himself") was a willful act of giving by the Father towards the Son. Once this "life in himself" was given, the Son shared the full divine essence with the Father, correct?

@RayButterworth I know what you mean... though I am not certain what I would delete yet. I've had this question open for several days. And it has been made larger and smaller multiple times. :)

@JsWitness No... I'm trying to say that a Trinitarian should respond to your question, in a deep manner by pointing out the flaw of the arian assumption within the question. By pointing out the entire passage is about Jesus comparing Himself to God, by claiming to be equal in works, love, power over death, authority, ´judgement, honor, and of course the eternal nature. (Aka, an elaborate way of saying I AM GOD)  And from an orthodox perspective the theology should direct one towards God.

@Wyrsa - If you'd only knew that I have no issue whatsoever with the statements that John 5 is about Jesus acting out the works, love, power over death, authority, honor of God the Father. The Father sent him for exactly that reason after all. I'm not interpreting anything into John 5:26, but am accepting the words as Jesus stated them - one would think that "given" is a simple / common verb, everybody knows what the verb means - and a child could understand the clear implications of the act of "giving". It's so simple!

@JsWitness All humanity has seen it; mortal gaze on it from afar. How great is God--Beyond our understanding! (Job 36:25-26) ... The Trinity has its source (πηγή) in the Father.  For more details about the main differences look at the answer from R. Brown here https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78944/how-do-orthodox-christians-explain-that-the-father-and-the-son-are-not-two-diffe

The answer provided is of Orthodox understanding. I believe during my researches that there might be different fundamental things that are different between different denominations.
